# Docker - transfer image of database with its content

Tags: docker, clickhouse

I want to pull an image of `yandex/clickhouse-server`

Then do with the database some stuff like creating tables, populate it with data and etc

And then I want to transfer the image with all its content to server.

How should I do this ?

Comment: Store data in the image itself? You don't want to do that. 1) image size will increase and 2) each container restart will load the same snapshot from the image, totally forgetting updates happened since last start. But maybe this _is_ what you want. :shrug:

Comment: You definitely should never store data of your databases in their docker images. Pull docker image from register, start it, then populate it with migrations (fill tables structure).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to move a database is creating a backup or dump and then reloading it into the new database. Otherwise if you want to you can try to build an image from the old container

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was to create image snapshot with `docker commit CONTAINER` but this  would **not** be clean solution.

The correct way would be to create some init file and extend basic image. 
On the docker [doc](https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/) page.

> How to extend this image
>   If you would like to do additional initialization in an image derived from this one, add one or more *.sql, *.sql.gz, or *.sh scripts under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. After the entrypoint calls initdb it will run any *.sql files, run any executable *.sh scripts, and source any non-executable *.sh scripts found in that directory to do further initialization before starting the service.
>
> For example, to add an additional user and database, add the following
>   to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sh: